# B-Tree deletion in a single pass

Tags: algorithm, tree, b-tree

Is it possible to remove an element from a B-Tree in a single pass?

Wikipedia says "Do a single pass down the tree, but before entering (visiting) a node, restructure the tree so that once the key to be deleted is encountered, it can be deleted without triggering the need for any further restructuring"
but doesn't say anything about how it is done.

Google only gives me the process of removing an element having to reestructure the tree.

Cormen also doesn't say anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in a variant of B+ tree called [PO-B+ tree](http://www.vldb.org/conf/1985/P331.PDF). In this "preparatory operations B+ tree" *the number of keys in a node may be between n-1 and 2n+1 rather than n and 2n in the usual B+-tree* (quoted from the paper). For delete operation (called *PO-delete* in the paper) you just merge (called "catenate" in the paper) all the nodes (except the root) that could be merged (or take a key from a neighbor), while moving toward the leaf. For *PO-insert* operation you split all the nodes (including the root). The description is given in the paper.

This preemptive restructuring only makes sense if the tree is used in multi-threaded environment, as it reduces the locking, and increases the concurency. It does not pay if a tree is accessed by only one actor.

Comment: well, I think I'll stick to the default deletion... Thanks!